# UIPanGestureRecognnizer in UIView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uipangesturerecognizer

I've implemented a UIPanGestureRecognizer in a UIView graph I have made, with the intent of moving it around in the frame of another UIView, which has the same dimensions. However when running it moves all over the frame of the ViewController view (the whole screen) and it not restricted to the smaller frame of its parent UIView I have set up. Here's some screen shots of the graph moving around:

[image: Initial image, before panning]
[image: Image after panning]

Here's the code for the parent (container) UIView which houses the GraphView class I have made:

```
class GraphViewDynamic:UIView {

var graphView:GraphView?

init(frame: CGRect, _ backgroudColor:UIColor, _ delegate:GraphViewDelegate) {

    super.init(frame:frame)

    self.graphView = GraphView.init(frame: frame, backgroudColor, delegate)

    self.addSubview(self.graphView!)
}

func graphData(dataSetName setNames: [String], _ lineColors:[UIColor], _ timeInterval:GraphViewTimeInterval) {

    if let _ = graphView {

        graphView?.graphData(dataSetName: setNames, lineColors, timeInterval)
    }
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

and here's the code in my GraphView UIView for the pan gesture handler:

```
func handlePan(_ sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    sender.view?.center = sender.location(in: sender.view?.superview)
}
```

Any ideas on how to restrict the panning to the specified frame of the parent UIView of my GraphView (which has the same dimensions)? Thanks for any help.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? Does it get clipped by the parent view? Is it just not allowed to move outside the view? In the latter case, you will need to add more code in `handlePan(_:)` that prevents the view from moving too far.

Comment: Yeah, I'd like it to be clipped by the parent view, that is, be restricted to moving inside the frame of the parent view.

Comment: Well to clip it, just set the parent view's `clipsToBounds = true`.

Comment: Awesome, it works fine. I use that property all the time for UILabels but didn't think to use it for this. Thanks very much.